# How do I create a dispatch table in Perl with key contain whitespace and the subroutine accepting an array parameter?

Tags: perl, dispatch-table

Here's my current thinking, but I dont know how to dispatch/execute it

```
my $key;
my @arraydata;

my %commandfunc{
"ab 1", \&func1(\@arraydata),
"ab 2", \&func2(\@arraydata,
"ab 3", \&func3(\@arraydata)
};

foreach $k (keys %commandfunc){
  if($something =~ /$k/){ #if $something match with a key string
        $key= $k;
        #some processing arraydata here;
    }

}
#dispatching??
my $command = $commandfunc{$key}->(\@arraydata);
```

Please correct my code..
Thanks alot

Comment: you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281456/how-do-i-implement-dispatch-tables-in-perl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashes are initialized with regular parens ( `( )` ), not curly brackets (those are for hash *references*.) And you initialize a hash with a list assignment. So the first part should be:

```
my %commandfunc = ( 
    "ab 1" => \&func1,
    "ab 2" => \&func2,
    "ab 3" => \&func3
);
```

The `=>` operator is a little prettier than using a comma and has the added benefit of quoting barewords on the left side, if necessary.

I'm not sure what you're trying to match in your loop (where does `$_` come from?) But you can do something like this:

```
foreach my $k (keys %commandfunc) {
    if( $something =~ /$k/) {
        my $result = $commandfunc{$k}->( \@arraydata );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`\&func1` is a subroutine reference, but `\&func1(\@arraydata)` is a reference to the value returned by a call to &func1.  Try instead just: `"ab 1" => \&func1, ...`.  The passing of @arraydata is correct in your dispatch code.

Note that `/$k/` will make metacharacters like . or * have their special effect in the regex; if you don't want that, do `/\Q$k/` instead.  Or possibly you want just `eq $k`?

Answer (score 4):

You weren't really clear whether `@arraydata` was defined up front or not, and how often this code would be executed. A direct translation of your attempt would yield:

```
my %commandfunc = (
    "ab 1" => sub { func1(@arraydata) },
    "ab 2" => sub { func2(@arraydata) },
    "ab 3" => sub { func3(@arraydata) },
};

if (my ($match) = grep { $_ eq $key } keys %commandfunc)
{
    my $result = &{$commandfunc{$match}};
}
```

However this is not very efficient - the `%commandfunc` hash is being defined with anonymous subroutine [closures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What%27s-a-closure%3f), when we could instead just store coderefs to the original subs with no arguments bound, and pass in an array later:

```
my %commandfunc = (
    "ab 1" => \&func1,
    "ab 2" => \&func2,
    "ab 3" => \&func3,
};
```

and call it like this:

```
my $result = $commandfunc{$match}->(@array);
```

Comment: looking at mhd's code, I decided that since @arraydata was being passed at the time of dispatch, this couldn't be what he meant.

Comment: @ysth: aye, so making a table of simple coderefs would be more appropriate then.