# How can I use dispatch tables in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, dispatch-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I implement dispatch tables in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281456/how-do-i-implement-dispatch-tables-in-perl)

I have a hash table that contains commands such as int(rand()) etc.
How do I execute those commands?

Comment: Duplicate: "How do I implement dispatch tables in Perl?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281456/how-do-i-implement-dispatch-tables-in-perl

Comment: Hashes hold scalar values. It could be helpful for providing relevant examples in answers if you described (with code) how you stored "commands" in the hash in the first place. Perl code in a string? Subroutine reference? Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`eval($str)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) to execute Perl code you store in a string variable, `$str`. You could alternatively store your code as function references within a hash, so something like:

```
$hash{'random'} = sub { int(rand()) };
```

This way, you could write `$hash{'random'}->()` to execute the function whenever you want a random value.

See also [Implementing Dispatch Tables](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=456530) on PerlMonks.

Comment: `eval` is almost never the best way to do it (where "it" == pretty much anything). Anonymous subrefs would be much better.

Comment: **String eval** is almost never the best way to do it.  Block eval is another story.

Answer (score 1):

As other have said, you can execute them using `eval`. However, please note that executing arbitrary strings of possibly tainted origin via `eval` is a major security hole, as well as prone to be slow if performance of your application matters.

You can use the [Safe module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Safe.html) to remove the security hole (not sure how bulletproof that is but much better than naked `eval`), but performance issues will always be there as Perl will have to compile your code prior to executing it WHILE executing the main program.

Comment: Please don't say *random* when you mean *arbitrary*, especially since the intended string would contain a call to `rand`, so it sounds like you're saying that that's somehow relevant, even though it's not. The security hole is that the string might come from an external source (like the user, or a text file).